# Checking to see if image to be used for background-image has loaded using new Image()?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to trigger an onLoad event for `@material-ui`'s `<CardMedia/>` component. By default, it loads the image in a `div` as a `background-image`. Although it does have an option for setting an `img` component - you can't define a custom `img` component, and it doesn't expose `Img` props either. It only takes a media `src`.

This has made it difficult (for me) to check for onLoad events on the image.

My first thought was to use `new Image()` to load an image and then re-use that image's src in the `<CardMedia />` component. Is that valid code or am I just loading the same image twice?

For example,

https://codesandbox.io/s/cardmedia-onload-tuqru

Quick look:

```
...

const handleImageLoaded = () => setImgIsLoading(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const image = new Image();
    image.onload = handleImageLoaded;
    image.src = src ? `/t/width=500/matte=none/scale/f${src}/scaled.jpg` : undefined;
    setImg(image);
}, []);

return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
        <div className={classes.itemRoot}>
            {imgIsLoading && <Skeleton variant="rect" className={classes.skeleton} />}
            {!imgIsLoading && (
                <img
                    src={img.src}
                    alt={alt}
                />
            )}
        </div>
    </div>
);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's valid since the same image URL will only load once no matter how many instances of an image object you have with the same URL.